# Is my pair better than my opponent's pair?

Tags: texas-hold-em

I have a pair of eights in my hand and my opponent has a Jack and a Queen in her hand. If a Jack turned up on the flop, does my pair of eights still win ?

Comment: Why didn't you search for an answer to this online ? Every `Poker Tuturial 101` page out there contains sufficient information to figure out an answer to this. It's maximum 10 minutes of Googling. I downvoted your question for lack of research effort.

Comment: @Crizly since the question pertains to the person with QJ pairing their J (not the odds of it, but the meaning of it having happened), I'd say this question is not about odds but rather is about rules. They're asking if their pocket pair, while smaller, beats a non-pocket pair. I believe you overlooked that because of the raw simplicity of it, but what's simple understanding to someone that understands the rules is not so basic to someone that doesn't yet know them.

Comment: @mah - Oh, misread the questions, my bad

Answer (score 2):

The rank of the cards is what makes the difference here: since a Jack is bigger than an Eight<sup>1</sup>, your opponent's pair of Jacks is bigger than your pair of Eights, so your opponents is winning at that point.

<sup>1</sup> = the ranks of the cards, in increasing order is: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace. A bigger card has more "power".

Answer (score 1):

You are losing once he flopped the pair of jacks.

If an 8 appears on the turn (about a 10% chance) or river (about a 5% chance) then you would win with three 8s, also called three of a kind.

Comment: The chance of an 8 appearing on the river is higher than on the turn, unless it also appeared on the turn, in which case he'd have quads.